# JSON.parse() in AJAX response says undefined, why?

Tags: php, json, ajax

I have been working on this little app which sends an **AJAX** **GET request** to an URL which gives a **JSON** reply with **PHP** `json_encode()` function and when I try to access any individual response **JSON** value, it says undefined but the `console.log()` of the whole response gives me **VALID JSON**!
[image: The JSON issue]

What am I doing wrong here please?

UPDATE with code:
The code is written using Codeigniter. Here is the server side code.

```
public function getByIdModel($id){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `pop_proj` WHERE `id`= $id";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    $result = $query->result();
    return json_encode($result );
} 
public function getByIdController() {
    $this->load->model('Crud_model');
    $query = $this->Crud_model->getById('394857');

    echo json_encode($query);
}
```

Comment: If you are sending back a JSON, you normally don't even need to use JSON.parse() - just ensure to include the correct [header](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4064468/1022914). You may also think about simplifying by using [$.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/).

Comment: JSON.stringify(data) logs this-
"[{\"id\":\"394857\",\"fips\":\"6097\",\"county\":\"SONOMA\",\"date_year\":\"1995\",\"age\":\"12\",\"pop_male\":\"2986\",\"pop_female\":\"3252\"}]"

Comment: I'd suggest to set correct "Accept" headers as @Mikey suggested, so that jQuery will do JSON.parse for you. Then I'd suggest using Debugger and see your data on the each step https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/

Comment: In your Chrome browser, analyze your response. Inspect > Network tab > XHR > click the request > look at Response Headers' Content-Type. It should say `application/json`.

Comment: If you explicitly set `dataType: 'JSON'` in your `.ajax` options, then you don't need to parse the response, as it will already be an object to use. Default is 'smart', which may have already turned it into an object as well, thus trying to json.parse an object will result in ... not good data.

Comment: Please show your PHP code where you are outputting your response.

Comment: $sql = "SELECT * FROM `pop_proj`";
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
$result = $query->result();
return json_encode($result);

As @Musa suggested in the answer below, double JSON.parse() fixes this. What is the standard procedure then?

Comment: "Standard procedure" is to (1) set the header and (2) use echo/print as shown in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064444/returning-json-from-a-php-script/4064468#4064468).

Answer (score 4):

It looks like `data` is a string, that would mean `response` is double encoded.

Try `var data = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(response));`

If that works go to your server side code and fix the double encoding and ofcourse remove the double parsing on the client side.

---

I'm guessing `getById` calls `getByIdModel` both calls `json_encode`, I would remove it from `getByIdModel` so your data isn't encoded twice.

---

With respect to the whole json parsing point, if your ajax request expects json set the `dataType` parameter to JSON and then the response in your success function will parsed to their JavaScript native type.

Comment: If the OP has to resort to using not just one but two `JSON.parse()` I would bet that his response is not coming back as a JSON.

Comment: This works and fixes the undefined problem! I am requesting mysql to serve me the records, I json_encode() the result with php and in the ajax end JSON.parse them and the undefined problem shows up. 
When I double JSON.parse(), the problem goes away. Should I not JSON.parse or should I not json_encode() with php? Where am I double encoding?

Comment: it would have to be somewhere in your php code, post it so we can see

Comment: $sql = "SELECT * FROM pop_proj"; $query = $this->db->query($sql); $result = $query->result(); return json_encode($result); Here it is.

Comment: This looks like some kind of framework you're using, what is it and update the question with the code, the full function.